# What will be XPath of YouTube channel description?

Tags: xpath, youtube, google-sheets-formula

I tried too much to find out [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheGabeFix/about) Description  but normal Xpaths does not working like

This one //*[@id="description-container"]  and //*[@id="description"] both fail i also tried with property="og:description" it does not provide full Description,

Any One can help please and also can tell me the source the YT Xpaths / class elements?

Comment: `//*[@id="description"]` is for Youtube videos description

Answer (score 1):

Just use this XPath :

```
//div[@class='about-description branded-page-box-padding']
```

Output :

[image: YTDesc]

Comment: E. Wiest Thanks a lot, can I know where did you get this class "about-description branded-page-box-padding"? I search for it but not get it.

Comment: It comes from the page content when you download then parse it (with R, Python,etc.). The html structure is a bit different from what is rendered in the browser.